# how to read and edit .resx file

Tags: asp.net, resources, resx

hey guys,
i have an asp.net website. which has resource file, which contains a key known as `ControlTitle_userarticlemanage.Text` whose value is set to create/edit article. now i want to manage this key at runtime, now there is a page which has edit and add button when user clicks on add the title should be create/edit article else my article...

so i want to update the `ControlTitle_userarticlemanage.Text` key in resx file.
Please any one can suggest anything for the same.

Comment: I think these articles would be helpful for you: 1. [Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization Resource Provider and Editor](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/) 2. [Updatable ASP.NET ResX Resource Provider – yes, it’s possible!](http://web.archive.org/web/20100126064839/http://www.onpreinit.com/2009/06/updatable-aspnet-resx-resource-provider.html)